# Using Omega to prove a lemma in Coq

Tags: coq, proof, induction

I am trying to make a proof in Coq using Omega. I spent a lot of time on it, but nothing came to me. I have to say I am new in Coq, so I am not at ease with this kind of language, and I do not have much experience. But I am working on it.

Here's the code I have to prove:

```
Require Import Arith Omega.

Fixpoint div2 (n : nat) :=
 match n with
   S (S p) => S (div2 p)
 | _ => 0
 end.

Fixpoint mod2 (n : nat) :=
 match n with
   S (S p) => mod2 p
 | x => x
 end.
```

To make this proof, I thought it would help to prove by induction this lemma first:

```
Lemma div2_eq : forall n, 2 * div2 n + mod2 n = n.
```

Then this one, using omega and div2_eq :

```
Lemma div2_le : forall n, div2 n <= n.
```

But I did not manage to go further.

Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily derive induction principles from the functions `div2` and `mod2` like so:

```
Functional Scheme div2_ind := Induction for div2 Sort Prop.
Functional Scheme mod2_ind := Induction for mod2 Sort Prop.
```

`div2_ind` and `mod2_ind` have more or less types:

```
forall P1,
  P1 0 0 ->
  P1 1 0 ->
  (forall n1, P1 n1 (div2 n1) -> P1 (S (S n1)) (S (div2 n1))) ->
  forall n1, P1 n1 (div2 n1)

forall P1,
  P1 0 0 ->
  P1 1 1 ->
  (forall n1, P1 n1 (mod2 n1) -> P1 (S (S n1)) (mod2 n1)) ->
  forall n1, P1 n1 (mod2 n1)
```

To apply these theorems you can conveniently write `functional induction (div2 n)` or `functional induction (mod2 n)` where you might usually write `induction n`.

But a stronger induction principle is associated with these functions:

```
Lemma nat_ind_alt : forall P1 : nat -> Prop,
  P1 0 ->
  P1 1 ->
  (forall n1, P1 n1 -> P1 (S (S n1))) ->
  forall n1, P1 n1.
Proof.
intros P1 H1 H2 H3. induction n1 as [[| [| n1]] H4] using lt_wf_ind.
  info_auto.
  info_auto.
  info_auto.
Qed.
```

In fact, the domain of any function is a clue to a useful induction principle. For example, the induction principle associated to the domain of the functions `plus : nat -> nat -> nat` and `mult : nat -> nat -> nat` is just structural induction. Which makes me wonder why `Functional Scheme` doesn't just generate these more general principles instead.

In any case, the proofs of your theorems then become:

```
Lemma div2_eq : forall n, 2 * div2 n + mod2 n = n.
Proof.
induction n as [| | n1 H1] using nat_ind_alt.
  simpl in *. omega.
  simpl in *. omega.
  simpl in *. omega.
Qed.

Lemma div2_le : forall n, div2 n <= n.
Proof.
induction n as [| | n1 H1] using nat_ind_alt.
  simpl. omega.
  simpl. omega.
  simpl. omega.
Qed.
```

You should familiarize yourself with functional induction, but more importantly, you should really familiarize yourself with well-founded induction.